# Some apps haven't been configured to use Apple's SKAdNetwork

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, admob, skadnetwork

After I publish my Flutter app on Apple App Store Admob gave this warning.

> Some apps haven't been configured to use Apple's SKAdNetwork
>
> To ensure you're getting credit for all ads activity, like app
> installs, be sure to configure SKAdNetwork with Google's network IDs.

When I click "Get instructions" button. It opens this page:
https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/ios14?hl=en-GB

But as you know, this page is not for Flutter. This page is for Native iOS apps developing by Swift or Objective-C.

How can I configure Apple's SKAdNetwork in Flutter? Where to edit - change?

Interestingly, there is no source for this problem in the Internet.

I feel like the first person in the world to develop Flutter.

Really, there is no solution - no source in Flutter for this problem!

**Note:** There is no information about this problem in this source too:
https://developers.google.com/admob/flutter/quick-start#ios

**EDIT:** Must I implement ATT to configure SKAdNetwork? What happens if I only change Info.plist?

https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/ios14?hl=en-GB#request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem, this warning has been removed automatically. I was using out-dated admob SDK.

https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads/install

**SOLUTION:**
Update your admob SDK to latest version.

I edited my **pubspec.yaml** file.

```
dependencies:
  google_mobile_ads: ^1.0.1
```

I updated my app on App Store so no warning is seen now in Admob Panel.

Answer (score 1):

Even with flutter applications, you have different configuration files for iOS and Android.
Look for the `Info.plist` file within your project (you must have one, usually under `ios/Runner` and update the keys as mentioned in the link you have attached

Comment: What do you think about requesting app tracking transparency authorization? https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/ios14?hl=en-GB#request Must I implement this to configure SKAdNetwork? Or is it different thing or optional? There are some code in this part, this is not for Flutter, for Native apps(swift, objective-c)

Comment: According to Apple developer guidelines if you share user information with 3rd party tools you should get the user content with this permission. Saying that, you don't have to do it, though it is recommended. It is a kind of a grey area that I personally don't like to go in with Apple. AFAIK some Ads SDKs won't pass the relevant information until they see this permission. If you